# Netbeans Multi-line Regular Expression Search

Tags: regex, netbeans

I'm trying to search for all the HTML input tags with a type of 'text' inside Netbeans 6.9.

Does Netbeans support searching for string using regular expressions with different search criteria spread across multiple lines or does it only work within a single line?

This regular expression

```
<input.*type=['"]text['"].*/>
```

works when the entire tag and its attributes are written in a single line like this

```
<input name="data[something]" id="some_id" value="some_value" type="text" />
```

But because I avoid writing long lines of code and break them as such

```
<input name="data[something]" id="some_id"
       value="some_value" type="text" />
```

the same regular expression does not work.

Is there a way this could be achieved?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, the `.` metacharacter doesn't match newlines.  There should be an option called "Single-line" or "DOTALL" or similar, that lets the dot match *every* character.  Or you could add `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex and get the same effect for just that regex.

But it would be better to replace the `.*` with `[^<>]*`.  In DOTALL mode, `.*` will try to gobble up the whole rest of the document, resulting in slow performance and/or incorrect matches,  but `[^<>]*` will never try to match beyond the end of the tag.

By the way, if you're using `['|"]` to match a single-quote or a double-quote, get rid of the `|`.  "OR" is implied in a character class, so you only need `['"]` (the `|` would simply match a literal `|`).

Comment: I have a similar problem and your answer helped me. But another problem appeared -- my regex remains greedy. Where can I read more about that "(?s) at the beginning" stuff? Can I make my regex non greedy with that? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I've found it. `(.*)` - greedy, `(.*?)` - non greedy.

Comment: (?s) did helped in finding matches where .(dot) included new line, thank you very much!